# Why load index.js twice with react-native-navigation on ios [debug]

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I create a new react-native project and integrate with RNN.
I find index.js is loaded twice and all components are constructed twice when debugging on ios simulator/device.

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.8",
"react-native-navigation": "^2.26.5" 



@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Might be due to debug mode. Are you able to replicate in a production build?

Comment: @TomRiglar yes, It's ok in the production build. But it is weird in the debug build.